# Qt QWidget изменение размера

Tags: c++, qt, resize

При нажатии на кнопку вызывается функция:

```
void MainWindow::MenuN_1()
{
    QWidget *widget = new QWidget();
    widget->setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 800, 250));
    widget->resize(200,300);

    QFormLayout *form = new QFormLayout(widget);
    n1le_number1 = new QLineEdit;
    n1le_number2 = new QLineEdit;
    n1l_answer = new QLabel();

    QPushButton *pb_check = new QPushButton("Сравнить");

    form->setWidget(0, QFormLayout::FieldRole, n1le_number1);
    form->setWidget(1, QFormLayout::FieldRole, n1le_number2);
    form->setWidget(3, QFormLayout::FieldRole, n1l_answer);
    form->setWidget(2, QFormLayout::FieldRole, pb_check);

    QPushButton *cancel = new QPushButton("Назад");
    form->setWidget(4, QFormLayout::FieldRole, cancel);

    setCentralWidget(widget);

    connect(cancel, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(Menu1()));    
    connect(pb_check, SIGNAL (clicked()), this, SLOT (pb_pressedN1()));
}
```

Инетресует вопрос, почему ни setGeometry, ни resize не влияют на размер и положение окна?

Я бы хотел, чтобы у окна был минимальный размер (видны полностью виджеты, но нет пустого пространства)

Comment: Если вам необходимо именно фиксированные размер задать, то есть метод setFixedSize. Но с layout-ами наверное лучше.

Answer (score 1):

Дело в том, что после того как `widget` становится дочерним окном `MainWindow`, он перестает контролировать свой размер и положение, и необходимо устанавливать размер самого `MainWindow`. То есть setGeometry и resize влияют только на виджеты верхнего уровня.

Так же имеются средства для управления размещением виджетов внутри Layout'ов. Виджет может указать свои минимально и максимально приемлимые размеры, и то как их использовать. Смотрите документацию по layout: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html#adding-widgets-to-a-layout